# How to bookmark pages that have dynamic URLs?

Tags: plugins, bookmark

I display stock data on a WP page using the stock ticker symbol as a URL parameter, example:  `..../stocks/?tsla`  (page will display Tesla stock information).

Now I want to add a "Bookmark this page" button, ideally using one of the various WP bookmark plugins, to display a list of all user-specific bookmarks on a separate page on my site. All plugins I have found so far support bookmarking a WP *page*, but not a *specific URL* with a parameter as above. I am looking for a bookmark plugin which *differentiates* between the URL `..../stocks/?tsla` and the URL `..../stocks/?aapl`

Any advice where I could find such a plugin or a code solution, alternatively?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE - plugin recommendations are considered off-topic here, however.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

A function in your theme would be fairly easy to write up.  Using `the_permalink()` or pulling the request property from the global $wp object itself.

Comment: https://www.thewebflash.com/how-to-add-a-cross-browser-add-to-favorites-bookmark-button-to-your-website/